# Using Selenium to extract text...but text has 0 opacity

Tags: python, css, selenium

I need to extract the text within the class "one".
I have the following code:

```
h3 = browser.find_element_by_class_name("one")

h3 = h3.text

print(h3)
```

The problem is that the result is an empty string...it seems nothing is printed out.
Upon further inspection, the text within this class has an opacity of "0". I am assuming this is causing the issue. How do I get around this?

Comment: Please share the html representation of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
el = browser.find_element_by_class_name("one")
print el.get_attribute('innerHTML')
> Success
```

WebElement.text is aware of CSS styling, so `el.text` returns a blank line, while `el.get_attribute('innerHTML')` will return the html (in this case, just text) inside.

Alternatively, if you want to use the `.text` property, you can alter the CSS to make the text visible. In this particular case, it's not just the opacity but also the display and visibility styles of containing `div`s that you'd need to modify. For example:

```
browser.execute_script("var a = document.getElementById('result-error').style; a.display = 'block'; a.visibility = 'visible'; a.opacity = 100;")
el = browser.find_element_by_class_name("one")
print el.text
```

But `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` is less intrusive and works just fine for what you're trying to do here.

**Update 1:**

Since I don't know exactly what your requirements are, here's my code that grabs all the elements with class "one" from https://www.voilanorbert.com/ and prints out the `innerHTML` for each of them:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.voilanorbert.com/')

ones = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('one')

for el in ones:
    print el.get_attribute('innerHTML')

driver.close()

> Oh man, I broke my ankle
> Nothing found
> Catch-all
> Success
> I'm tired
```

Comment: Your code works for me in this case and prints "Success". Are you sure you don't have any other elements that also have class "one"?

Comment: I want to to extract the text within class "one", so "Success". This website has multiple possible results for the text within this class. So this is one of the four possibilties for the "one" class.

Comment: @ohbrobig I'm sorry, you were correct that the CSS was hiding the text from the `WebElement.text` property! Thanks for teaching me this. I've updated my answer with a suggestion to use `.get_attribute("innerHTML")`.

Comment: Ok, so the "get_attribute" method doesn't bring up the right results. It brings up the HTML of the first instance of class "one", even though that is not the one displayed...

Comment: The execute script method brings up an error saying "unknown error function not defined"

Comment: @ohbrobig `find_element_by_class_name` only returns the first matching element on the page. If you want a list of all of the elements, use `find_elements_by_class_name`. Since I am not sure what you need exactly, I have pasted in my code as an update to my answer above. Please take a look and see if it answers your question.

Comment: @ohbrobig Does the above update help answer the question you posted?

Comment: Somewhat...another user chimed on a related question

Comment: @ohbrobig Ok! If you feel that my answer addresses the question you posted here, please consider marking it as accepted. If you don't feel that my answer addressed your question well enough, please let me know where it's falling short, and I will try to improve it.